# thread pool monitoring a task queue design

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, infinite-loop

I need a multi-thread system to monitor a task queue. If there are tasks in the queue, the multi-thread system should execute the task, if the task is successfully finished, the task is deleted from the queue, if not, the task should be re-added to the queue, and wait for the next time to be executed.

With this purpose, I design a dead loop to poll one task from the queue every time, and `submit` the task in the queue to the thread pool, use the `Future` mechanism the get the result of the task, if the task is failed, add the task to the end of the queue, and wait for the next result.

Is the dead loop is good for this situation? Is there any better suggestions for me?

Comment: What is a "dead loop"?  If you have  a question about code that you have written, then show us the code.

Comment: @jameslarge I'm sorry, it means `infinite-loop`.

Comment: @jameslarge My test code is here: [link](https://github.com/ninglee/coderlabs/tree/master/src/org/coderlabs/study)